# React Router onEnter not working as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am building a basic react-login app for educational purposes and to authenticate a route I am using React-router's onEnter prop functionality

```
import axios from 'axios';    

var Authentication = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
    axios.get('/api/getuser')
    .then((res) => {
        if(res.data != '') {
          replace('account/wall')
        }
        callback()
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        callback()
    })

}

export default (
  <Route component={Root}  >
      <Route path='/' component={Home} onEnter={Authentication}/>
      <Route path='/login' component={Login} onEnter={Authentication}/> 
      <Route path='/signup' component={Registration} onEnter={Authentication}/> 
      <Route path='/account/wall' component={Wall}/>
      <Route path='*' component={Notfound} />
  </Route>

);
```

Everything is working as intended But it is beyond me why the router render the Home component for a blink second and THEN replace the route to `/account/wall` when I try `/` route after logging in?? Same thing happen if I try `/login` or `/signup` after logging in., Is there anyway to fix this behavior ??

I already tried to solve this by authenticating the user in componentWillMount method (which is not the react way i guess) by rendering empty `<div>` when checking for user but that also renders empty page for a blink second and not the correct way to do it.

So I just want to render `/account/wall` if user is authenticated without any middleware renders. What can I do??

Comment: what you need is Higher Order Component for checking authentication,  check this http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/1185/components/4649/creating-components#t=20161019121953341148

Comment: @abhirathore2006 Can you please post an answer as to what changes I have to make.. What I did is not working anymore..

Comment: @abhirathore2006 your example does not explain how higher order component will help me with programatically routing to a different route without rending the component which is being checked by onEnter function. Do you have a better example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't write the exact example because everyone's implementation differs, but I am going to right a HelloWrapper component example which wraps any component and if it receive the sayHello prop to true, it render the Hello instead of actual component, you can check the login props and redirect or show login component..in your case.

1. Write a function to copy props form actual component to wrapper

HoistNonReactStatistics.tsx  or jsx ( I use typescript)

```
    const REACT_STATICS = {
    childContextTypes: true,
    contextTypes: true,
    defaultProps: true,
    displayName: true,
    getDefaultProps: true,
    mixins: true,
    propTypes: true,
    type: true
    };

    const KNOWN_STATICS = {
    name: true,
    length: true,
    prototype: true,
    caller: true,
    arguments: true,
    arity: true
    };

    export default function hoistStatics(targetComponent, sourceComponent) {
    var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(sourceComponent);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
      const key = keys[i];
      if (!REACT_STATICS[key] && !KNOWN_STATICS[key]) {
        try {
          targetComponent[key] = sourceComponent[key];
        } catch (error) {}
      }
    }
    return targetComponent;
    }
```

2. write wrapper function which will return wrapped component

   ```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import HoistNonReactStatistics from "./HoistNonReactStatistics"
    export function HelloWrapper(){

    return function HellowWrapComponent(DecoratedComponent) {

    class WrappendComponent extends React.Component<{sayHello?:boolean},{}>{
       constructor(props){
         super(props);
       }
       componentWillMount(){
        /** do some login check here and redirect if required **/
        }
       componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        /** do some login check here and redirect if required **/
        }
      render(){
        if(this.props.sayHello){
          return <div>Hello</div>
        }else{
          return <DecoratedComponent />
        }
      }
    }
    /** if you use redux then also apply the connect method on return component so it get access to required auth reducer data**/
    return HoistNonReactStatistics(WrappendComponent,DecoratedComponent);
    }
   }
   ```

   3. create a const  ( not sure if this step is required for jsx, however typescript doesn't allow to wrap a component directly because I didn't declare wrapper function to accept arguments

   `export const requireHellow = HelloWrapper();`

   4. now warp any component with function, I used it at the time of export but you can also do it in Route's component prop

   `export default requireHellow(SomeComponent);`

now whenever you use this SomeComponent and it has **sayHello prop to true** it will render Hello otherwise render the actual component

Comment: Thank you for your answer abhi, but I decided to user jsonwebtoken for storing my user logged in status, so there is not need for the ajax call to check the user in the server stored sessions, which was causing the flashes.

Comment: @eersteam we use same but still we have this component , just to check if user is logged in or not, this component doesn't make use of ajax , it just check the redux state.  And you surely don't want to write same thing in every component

Comment: but we can also check for the jwt token in the onEnter of a route when a route is pushed right? is that possible or should i go for a wrapper component in form of HOC that do the checking for me?

Comment: HOC will be a better choice, because you can perform other stuffs in onenter then

Comment: Other stuff like what? and also what is the best place to store jwt after user logs in? I m currently storing it in browsers localStorage. but the thing is I cant access the localStorage on the onEnter function. So i guess using HOC is the only way here?

Comment: ALSO the localStorage is not accessible in the componentWillMount() as well... So where should I do the authentication ? If I do it in the componentDidMount() the wrapped component renders first and then redicrect happens

Comment: Create an auth reducer, whose initial state id read from local storage, and redux state will alwayd contain the updated token or no token....after login store the token in redux and store same in local storage,  then use redux connect to pass toKen to HOC

Comment: Well I'm not using Redux for now as I find using Alt.js much easier and relatable to flux architecture. Also I want to use react-cookie to store the token if that is a correct way to do it?. That way it will be accessible anywhere and solve my issue. But that said, I'm open to suggestions if storing in react-cookie is not the way to go...

Comment: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage this can help you in understand where to store the data

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>function requireAuth(nextState, replace,callback){
     var data = {
         token: store.getState().student.token,
         email: store.getState().student.email}
     makeUserRequest('post', data, '/api/auth')
     .then((res)=>{
            if (!res.data.success) {
                    replace({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname },  nextState.location.query)
            }
            callback()
     })
 }

return(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route path='/' component={app}>
  <IndexRoute  component={login} />
        <Route path='home' component={home} />
  <Route path='login' component={login} />
  <Route path='profile' component={profile} onEnter={requireAuth} />
</Route>
```

)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please consider adding some context to the answer, rather than just posting code.  That will make it easier for others to understand as well.