# How can I secure a component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-login

I have created two React components - `Login` and `Secure`. `Login` hosts the `FacebookLogin` component from [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@greatsumini/react-facebook-login).

When the button is pressed, it submits the login attempt and I get a successful response from Facebook. Next, the app should navigate to the `Secure` page, which I do using the `react-router-dom` package.

However, I found that I can just navigate directly to the `Secure` component in the URL. How can I make it so that any attempt to navigate to a secure page is redirected to the `Login` page first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking authentication in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625918/checking-authentication-in-react)

Comment: Are you [this guy](https://youtu.be/N7v0yvdkIHg)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [that component's documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@greatsumini/react-facebook-login), you can get the login status in code:

```
FacebookLoginClient.login((res) => {
  // "res" contains information about the current user's logged-in status
});
```

So in any component that needs to know the status, simply reference the library:

```
import { FacebookLoginClient } from '@greatsumini/react-facebook-login';
```

And use that `FacebookLoginClient.login` to check the user's logged-in status.  If the status doesn't meet the criteria you define, redirect the user.  (For example, you can check this in a `useEffect` when the component first loads, or perhaps on every render if you're paranoid about it.)

---

For more detail on rendering the target component, since `useEffect` occurs after the initial render, you can rely on additional state to check.  For example, consider this structure:

```
const [canRender, setCanRender] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  FacebookLoginClient.login((res) => {
    // check the status and call "setCanRender" accordingly
  });
}, []);

if (!canRender) return <>Checking authentication...</>;

// your existing return for the component goes here
```

The idea here is to default the component to a kind of "loading state" and only render the "secure" content after the authentication has been verified.